# Best way for live RTMP streaming from dv camcorder

Tags: java, apache-flex, flash, streaming, rtmp

I herd about RED5, but unfortunately I can't find any examples for feeding it with external source. I know RTSP is in development, but I'm thinking about (named) pipes or something like this. There is is also project named xuggle that is as far as I understand ffmpeg wrapper for Java, but I herd they have also problems with live streaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WOWZA](http://www.wowzamedia.com/) is a well-known commercial solution.

They claim better performance and price than FMS.

There is always of course the Free and free [ffserver](http://ffmpeg.org/ffserver-doc.html) too!  There's nothing wrong with 'streaming' using progressive download of FLV.

Comment: I know Wowza, But probably I will not be allowed using it. I will try ffserver.

Answer (score 2):

[RTMPD](http://www.rtmpd.com/) is Free and free.

Its a struggle to build from source though.

Comment: Thank You. I must definitely try it. It looks very promising. There is little lack of documentation but I can handle it.

I was thinking about mammoth also, but it is in alpha stage.

Comment: The struggle comment doesn't seem like the case any more, I just built it from source on OSX without a single issue... trying to figure out how to run it now thou :)

Answer (score 1):

See the project http://livertmpjavapublisher.blogspot.com/2011/06/release-10.html. You should use byte[] decoded video as input data.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  If a simple 1 to 1 connection is all your after you should check out adobe's free peering system stratus: http://www.flashrealtime.com/tuts/p2p-in-flash.html .  But if your looking for one to many broadcasting its going to either take a bunch of money for an fms license or a lot of poking around in red5 or RMTPD

Comment: It will be live stream from conference. So it will be one to many. I was thinking about RED5, but there are some problems with live streaming. FME's licence allows using it only with FMS, and RED5 publisher is poor.

It would be nice if the software could work in Unix like headless environment.

Answer (score -1):

Try 3B NEXUS www.3bnexus.com. free rtmp flash player, simply add rtmp link and file key and embed to your site or add to playlist. We use their live streaming platform for internal comms.